# Sonar way with findbugs doesnt show Rules Complaince nor issues in maven projects

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm working with Jenkins and Sonar and trying to analyze a Maven Project (java) using 'Sonar way with FindBugs' profile, but when the exexution ends the RCI it's always 100% and it doesnt show the Issues and when I use 'Sonar Way' it works properly.
I have updated plugins but nothing works.

Jenkins Version:1.609.1
Sonar Version: 5.1.1
Maven version:3.3.3
SonarQue Runner version:2.4

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you make sure that you still have the Findbugs plugin installed? Indeed, Findbugs is not bundled with SonarQube distribution anymore.

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm not using 'FindBugs' I'm using 'Sonar way with FindBugs', I dont know they they use that pluging too, but it is installed.

Comment: Can you verify that your Sonar Way with FindBugs profile contains active rules?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.